# Error in semantic analysis: DATE, DATETIME, and TIMESTAMP types aren't supported yet. Please use STRING instead

Tags: hive

Is this exception because of hive version or some other issue?
Please provide me with a correct solution.

```
CREATE TABLE data_types_table (

 our_tinyint TINYINT,

 our_smallint SMALLINT ,

 our_int INT ,

 our_bigint BIGINT,

 our_float FLOAT,

 our_double DOUBLE,

 our_timestamp TIMESTAMP ,

 our_boolean BOOLEAN,

 our_string STRING,

 our_array ARRAY<TINYINT>,

 our_map MAP<STRING,INT>,

 our_struct STRUCT<f : SMALLINT, second : FLOAT, third : STRING>,

 our_union UNIONTYPE<INT,FLOAT,STRING>)

 ROW FORMAT DELIMITED

 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

 COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '|'

 MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '^'

 LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

 STORED AS TEXTFILE

 TBLPROPERTIES ('creator'='avi', 'created_at'='Mon May 18

20:46:32 EDT 2015');
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Hive version is **0.8** and above, then TIMESTAMP datatype will be supported.

If your Hive version is **0.12** and above, then DATE datatype will be supported.

Hive doesn't support DATETIME datatype.